# pop() Error: Index out of range python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone please explain why I get a list index out of range error??? I don't understand why, any help is appreciated.

```
 original_alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 original_alphabet_list = []
 for char in original_alphabet:
  original_alphabet_list.append(char)

 keyword_list = []
 for char in keyword:
  keyword_list.append(char)

 for value in keyword_list:
  for index in range(26):
   if value == original_alphabet_list[index]:
    original_alphabet_list.pop(index)
```

Comment: Could've sworn I've seen this question before.

Comment: As an aside, `original_alphabet_list = list(original_alphabet)`, no need for a for-loop.

Comment: Not sure how you can run something like that: `keyword_list.append(char`

Comment: Guess: change `for index in range(26):` to: `for index in range(len(original_alphabet_list)-1,-1, -1):`

Comment: Iterating over all the indices of a list while removing elements from it is as bad as removing elements while iterating over them directly.  Use a list comprehension `new_alphabet = [letter for letter in original_alphabet if letter not in keyword_list]`

Comment: alfasin thanks, your guess worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `list index out of range` error because you are removing an element from the same list which you are iterating:

```
original_alphabet_list.pop(index)
```

That's akin to cutting off the same branch of the tree on which you are sitting at the corner! The natural result is that you'll fall off.

When you remove an element, the indices in your original_alphabet_list are rearranged, hence the error as the index couldn't be found in the original list. For future reference, whenever you want to iterate through an array or dictionary, make a copy by slicing it on the iteration like this:

```
for value in keyword_list[:]:
    for index in range(26):
        if value == original_alphabet_list[index]: original_alphabet_list.pop(index)
```